# open Excel workbook with path obtained by python abspath

Tags: python, excel

I try to write a python script to open an Excel file and read the value of the first cell of a sheet. This works when I write the path name myself, but I want to make it dynamic. So whenever I change the location of the Excel file together with the python file I automatically have the right path name.

This is my script:

```
import xlrd
import time
from os.path import dirname, abspath

loc=dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
loc=loc+"\lijst.xlsx"

print("loc ->",loc)
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet1=wb.sheet_by_index(0)
naam=sheet1.cell_value(0,0)
print("naam: ",naam)
```

when I run this, I get an error message: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Tracy\Desktop\lijst.xlsx".

Why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to os.path.join for joining paths

changing

```
loc=loc+"\lijst.xlsx"
```

to

```
loc = os.path.join(loc, 'lijst.xlsx')
```

should work.